# How do I import and use the unicode function in Python 3?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a function (below) which uses a unicode function but I receive an "NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined" which leads me to believe I need to import unicode so I tried:

```
pip install unicode
```

then:

```
from unicode import unicode
```

and I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unicode'
```

The code that calls the unicode function is:

```
def makelist(table):
  result = []
  allrows = table.findAll('tr')
  for row in allrows:
    result.append([])
    allcols = row.findAll('td')
    for col in allcols:
      thestrings = [unicode(s) for s in col.findAll(text=True)]
      thetext = ''.join(thestrings)
      result[-1].append(thetext)
  return result
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that code snippet must be for Python 2, for which `unicode()` was a built-in function ready to be used without an import. In Python 3, literal strings are Unicode by default, so you don't need to explicitly cast them.